# Select single column in amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How to highlight a single column and deselect previously highlighted column in Column chart of amCharts 4?

I am trying to change the colors of all the columns before highlighting the color of target column, but it is not working properly.

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    ev.target.fill = am4core.color("red");
    chart.invalidate();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/j4m7frec/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `active` state for that:

```
var activeState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.fill = am4core.color('red');
```

In your `hit` event you can now set the columns to active. If you cache the last selected column, you can reset the `active` state before setting the new column to active:

```
var currentActive;
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  if (currentActive) {
    currentActive.isActive = false;
  }
  currentActive = ev.target;
  currentActive.isActive = true;
});
```

If you don't want to cache the last selection you can just deactivate a all columns before setting the new one:

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  series.columns.values.forEach(c => c.isActive = false);
  ev.target.isActive = true;
});
```

If you want to be able to unselect all columns again you can use this second method and extend it a bit:

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  series.columns.values
    .filter(c => c !== ev.target)
    .forEach(c => c.isActive = false);
  ev.target.isActive = !ev.target.isActive;
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmRZZr) is a code pen showing the last behavior. You just have to replace the last bit to use the other options.